# Copy JRE in distribution with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I developed a server with Java 16. Various other Java servers running on different Java versions run on almost all linux machines. So I can't use the Java pointed to by the JAVA_HOME variable. The start-scripts that Gradle generates use the JAVA_HOME. For me, that makes sense almost exclusively in Docker environments, doesn't it?

My requirements are:

- Gradle copies a JRE in the appropriate version into the directory /build/install/my_server/jre
- The start script uses the copied JRE.

I'm using Gradle's "application" and "distrubtion" plugin, but I couldn't find any settings that suit my needs. I cannot imagine that there is no standard solution for my requirements.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could just compile your code to the lowest possible Java version (for example 8), then any machine running 8 or above will be able to run it

Comment: may be jpackage can be of use in this use case
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html